# Eclipse tooltip popup font is blurry when debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-neon

I am using eclipse Neon Milestone 4 (4.6.0M4), dark Theme

When debugging, the font in the tooltip popup is blurry. See below:

[[image: hovers when debug]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a screen/display with a resolution like something 2560×1440 or so instead of something 'traditional' like 1920x1080?  Then this may be "high-DPI" related... see e.g. [Bug 399786](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399786) or [Bug 396063](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=396063) which sound a little similar, but not identical.

FYI [high-DPI is actively being worked on for Eclipse Neon](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479614), and getting better, but as of today not yet completed - give a bit more time, hopefully this will all be sorted by [Neon Release on Wednesday, June 22, 2016](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Neon/Simultaneous_Release_Plan).

Comment: No it was 1920x1080, the problem happens to Mars as well. Basically I have to stop using Dark Theme, then everything is fine.